# Element type is invalid: expected string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, mern

I'm trying to render react-bootstrap component, but it is throwing
react-dom.development.js:28439 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

The error is thrown when this part of code is insert

```
                    <Form.Group controlId='image'>
                        <Form.Label>Image</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type='text'
                            placeholder='Enter image url'
                            value={image}
                            onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
                        ></Form.Control>
                        <Form.File
                            id="image-file"
                            label="Choose File"
                            custom
                            onChange={uploadFileHandler}>
                        </Form.File>
                        {uploading && <Loader />}
                    </Form.Group>
```

The error is thrown when Form.File is inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such component "Form.File":

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Form.tsx#L65

Use FormControl with type="file" for it:

```
<Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
    <Form.Label>Default file input example</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="file" />
</Form.Group>
```

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/#file-input

Comment: really thanks man, it worked. Actually I was following a 4 year old video so maybe I got error